# I cannot see my pictures in flutter swiper

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter development. I cannot find my mistake. I can't see my images on my app. when I use them without slider it works what is wrong in my code can someone help me?

```
import 'package:feedme_start/widgets/Navigation_Drawer_Widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:flutter_swiper/flutter_swiper.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

final imageList = [
  "https://cdn.yeniakit.com.tr/images/news/625/pratik-degisik-yemek-tarifleri-en-sevilen-tarifler-h1581081558-3ff37b.jpg"
      "https://cdn.yemek.com/mncrop/940/625/uploads/2021/04/patlicanli-pilav-yemekcom.jpg"
];

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            title: Center(child: Text("FEED ME")),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.call))
            ],
          ),
          drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body:
           Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 200),
          child: imageSlider(context),
          ),
          
          

          /*Swiper(itemCount: imageList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Image.network(imageList[index],/*errorBuilder:
           (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace), {return const("resim yüklenemedi")},*/
          fit: BoxFit.cover,);
        },)*/
          ),
    );
  }
}


Swiper imageSlider(context){

return new Swiper(
  autoplay: true,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Image.network("https://cdn.yeniakit.com.tr/images/news/625/pratik-degisik-yemek-tarifleri-en-sevilen-tarifler-h1581081558-3ff37b.jpg",fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,);

  },
  itemCount: 10,
  viewportFraction: 0.8,
  scale: 0.9,
);

}
```

also here is the screenshots;

when I run the program it tries to upload the image. then it sends me the this screen and shows the 'rethrow' line error:

[image: when i run the program it tries to upload the image. then it sends me the this screen and shows the 'rethrow' line error]

after I continue debugging my screen looks like in the second picture:

[image: after i continue debugging my screen looks like in the second picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply forgetting to add `,` in your list.

A newline string after a string is considered as a string. For example, the following variable:

```
var text = "one two three"
           "four five six";
```

is the same as:

```
var text = "one two three" + "four five six";
```

So, instead of:

```
final imageList = [
  "https://cdn.yeniakit.com.tr/images/news/625/pratik-degisik-yemek-tarifleri-en-sevilen-tarifler-h1581081558-3ff37b.jpg"
  "https://cdn.yemek.com/mncrop/940/625/uploads/2021/04/patlicanli-pilav-yemekcom.jpg"
];
```

change to:

```
final imageList = [
  "https://cdn.yeniakit.com.tr/images/news/625/pratik-degisik-yemek-tarifleri-en-sevilen-tarifler-h1581081558-3ff37b.jpg" ,
  "https://cdn.yemek.com/mncrop/940/625/uploads/2021/04/patlicanli-pilav-yemekcom.jpg"
];
```